# How to provide _tcsdup function with char array in c++?

Tags: c++, windows

```
LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT("C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\EncryptZipFtp.exe"));
```

This notation works but I want to create command line manually. Like below:

```
char *fProg = "C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\EncryptZipFtp.exe";
char *fPath = "C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\Foto";
char *fPass = "wxRMKH1994wxRMK";

char command[500];
sprintf (command, "%s %s %s", fProg, fPath, fPass);
```

and usage:

```
LPTSTR szCmdline = _tcsdup(TEXT(command));
```

But it gives error `error C2065: 'Lcommand' : undeclared identifier`

What is the problem? Any help?

Comment: Why do you want to support MFC in DLL in Windows 98? Isn't that, like, a bit **archaic**?

Comment: I dont know. I just wanna use `CreateProcess` function instead of using `system("command")`

Answer (score 3):

The code you show is

- C code, not C++.
- For Windows 9x, not for modern Windows.
- `const`-incorrect to boot.
  (won't even compile with a conforming C++11-compiler).

In modern Windows use wide character strings. Replace

```
char *fProg = "C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\EncryptZipFtp.exe";
char *fPath = "C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\Foto";
char *fPass = "wxRMKH1994wxRMK";

char command[500];
sprintf (command, "%s %s %s", fProg, fPath, fPass);
```

with

```
wstring const fProg  = L"C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\EncryptZipFtp.exe";
wstring  const fPath = L"C:\\Users\\incemehm\\Desktop\\Foto";
wstring const fPass  = L"wxRMKH1994wxRMK";

wstring command = fProg + L' ' + fPath + L' ' + fPass;
```

where `wstring` is `std::wstring` from the `<string>` header.

Where you pass that to an API function, use `command.c_str()`.

---

Addendum: since the OP states in a comment that the intent is to pass this string to `CreateProcess`, do note that `CreateProcess` requires a *mutable* buffer. Thus you can't just pass `command.c_str()`. Instead copy this to another non-`const` `wstring` (easiest to by using `command` as initializer expression), let's say it's called `s`, add a terminating `L'\0'`, and pass `&s[0]`, …

```
wstring s = command + L'\0';
someFunc( &s[0] );
```

Comment: `wstring command = fProg + L' ' + fPath + L' ' + fPass; ` line gives the `no operator "+" matches these operands`

Comment: @MehmetInce: difficult to say what the problem is without seeing the code, but I guess you don't have a `using namespace std;` or a `using std::wstring`, or you've forgot to include the `<string>` header?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using TCHAR then use it throughout. eg:

```
TCHAR command[500];
_stprintf_s(command, _T("%s %s %s"), fProg, fPath, fPass);
```

You can also define an STL string as `typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR> tstring;` to use C++ strings of the appropriate type. But are you really going to compile without UNICODE defined?

Comment: It's quite counter-productive to use such monstrosities & complexity. Bad advice.